# Use pandas to split column and filled the other column with extracted values

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

class_name column contains both the name of course and cohort number.
I want to split column to two columns (name, cohort number)

FROM:

```
| class_name |

| introduction to programming 1th |
| introduction to programming 2th |
| introduction to programming 3th |
| introduction to programming 4th |
| algorithms and data structure 1th |
| algorithms and data structure 2th |
| object-oriented programming |
| database systems |
```

(I know it should be like 1st, 2nd, 3rd but the string is in my language and we use the same characters over and over after the number).

TO:

```
| class_name | class_cohort |

| introduction to programming | 1 |
| introduction to programming | 2 |
| introduction to programming | 3 |
| introduction to programming | 4 |
| algorithms and data structure | 1 |
| alrogithms and data structure | 2 |
| object-oriented programming | 1 |
| database systems | 1 |
```

Here is the code I have been working on:

```
import pandas as pd

course_count = 100
df = pd.read_csv("course.csv", nrows=course_count)

cols_interest=['class_name', 'class_department', 'class_type', 'student_target', 'student_enrolled']

df = df[cols_interest]
df.insert(1, 'class_cohort', 0)

# this is how I extract the numbers
df['class_name'].str.extract('(\d)').head()

# but I cannot figure out a way to copy those values into column 'class_cohort' which I filled with 0's.

# once I figure that out, I plan to discard the last digits
df['class_name'] = df['class_name'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
```

I briefly examined a solution where I would place commas all before 1th, 2th, 3th and then split the column using comma as delimiter but I couldn't figure out a way to replace \s1th -> ,1th for all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [indexing by positions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['class_cohort'] = df['class_name'].str[-3:-2]
df['class_name'] = df['class_name'].str[:-4]
print df
   class_name class_cohort
0       cs101            1
1       cs101            2
2       cs101            3
3       cs101            4
4  algorithms            1
5  algorithms            2
```

Or use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['class_cohort'] = df['class_name'].str.extract('(\d)')
df['class_name'] = df['class_name'].str[:-4]
print df
                      class_name class_cohort
0    introduction to programming            1
1    introduction to programming            2
2    introduction to programming            3
3    introduction to programming            4
4  algorithms and data structure            1
5  algorithms and data structure            2
```

Comment: There were some details I had left out - and \s+ wouldn't work in that case because course name consists of multiple words (1-6 words).

Comment: Thank you. Please check solution.

Comment: Thank you - `str.extract` works well. I have upvoted your answer but I am too much of a noob and my vote doesn't show publicly yet.

Comment: Btw, your question is very nice - you have input, desired output and what you try. Maybe you can remove `|` as columns, better are `2` - `3` spaces in next similar question. Glad can help you! Good luck!